# Why do C-style comments make insert statement run twice?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, oracle-xe

To make a long story short, I started getting ORA-00001 primary key violations and I tracked down the issue to the fact that some of my `INSERT INTO` statements were running twice. I then discovered that the offending commands had a C-style comment afterwards:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE

SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TIMING OFF
SET TIME OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET LINESIZE 120

SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

[...]

```
INSERT INTO INF_FIELD (FIELD_ID, CATEGORY_ID, COLUMN_EXPRESSION, DISPLAY_NAME, SORT_ORDER) VALUES (17, 1, 'FOO.NAME', 'Name of the foo', 17);

/*This is a comment*/
```

It was then easily fixed by switching to this syntax:

```
--This is a comment
```

What's the exact reason why `/*...*/` comments were making SQL*Plus run the statement twice?

Comment: Because / executes commands in SQL*PLus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* This is a comment */
```

Just make sure you have a space after `/*` , 
So it is treated as a single/multi line comment. And not mean to execute the last stored PL/SQL or SQL

To put it in detail.

What ever SQL*Plus interprets after `/` is ignored and it blindly pushes it's cached block into the server. Except for `/*` followed by a `new line` or `space`.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL;

D
-
X

SQL> /*t*/

D
-
X

SQL> /*
SQL> */
SQL> /

D
-
X

SQL> /*s

D
-
X
```

[From Document:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210024)

> You must enter a space after the slash-asterisk(/*) beginning a
>   comment.

Comment: Thank you for the link, yet that doc doesn't explain what it gets confused with (or why). As Paul points out in a comment, it's probably running the [slash operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yup, I was having the comment in mind, and wrote the answer as an extension to it!